# Convert to JSON from classes WP8

Tags: json, windows-phone-8

I need to send a json file to my server from my wp8 app. In android I am using a library which converts a class to a json file but I am new in WP and I don't know if there are something similar or I need to do concatenating strings

I already have all data in my class which has all methods get/set and constructor created properly.

Comment: Check out [JSON.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) - You can use: `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(...);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Newtonsoft.Json will help you Convert Object To Json.

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

var input = new { contactName = "ABCDEF", mobileNo1 = "1111111111", mobileNo2 = "1111111111"};
string jsonInput = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(input);
```

This links will help you;
[NuGet Gallery | Json.NET](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/), 
[Json.NET - Newtonsoft](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json), 
[Json.NET - Home](https://json.codeplex.com/)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. I was reding about it from the first answer and it worked like a charm from my already created class